# Syntax Error in Creating a Rule

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE INSERT_part_name AS
   ON INSERT TO partition.part_name
   DO INSTEAD select crm.dblink_exec('crm_server'::text, 'insert into partition.part_name(customerid, partition_name, partition, createdate) values('||new.customerid||','||quote_literal(new.partition_name)||',false'::text ||','||quote_literal(new.createdate))::timestamp without time zone);
```

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 3: ...uote_literal(new.createdate))::timestamp without time zone);
                                                                ^
```

Comment: Dont you see an issue with nested `'` ?

Comment: My guess is there is a `||` missing before it. Or `::timestamp without time zone` should be _within_ the quotes just before it. BTW: I dont like the _idea_ of putting a db_link inside a rule. Maybe I am too oldfashoned for that.

Comment: @karthikr
i dunno whether i got your point right or not...i have edited the above mentioned codings..But still i'm getting the error

Comment: @karthikr: There are no nested `'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the idea to use dblink in a RULE (did not test). But you have one closing `)` too many:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE INSERT_part_name AS
ON INSERT TO partition.part_name
DO INSTEAD SELECT crm.dblink_exec('crm_server'::text,
   'insert into partition.part_name(customerid, partition_name, partition, createdate)
    values(' || new.customerid || ',' || quote_literal(new.partition_name) || ',false'
    || ',' || quote_literal(new.createdate::timestamp without time zone));
```

I would use [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), though, for much cleaner code (requires Postgres 9.1+):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE INSERT_part_name AS
ON INSERT TO partition.part_name
DO INSTEAD SELECT crm.dblink_exec('crm_server'::text, format(
 'INSERT INTO partition.part_name(customerid, partition_name, partition, createdate)
  VALUES(%s, %L, false, %L)'
 ,NEW.customerid, NEW.partition_name, NEW.createdate::timestamp));
```